# Proof writing involving power set and cartesian product: $(P(A) \times P(B)) \subseteq P(A \times B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Prove: $(P(A) \times P(B)) ⊆ P(A \times B)$**

Suppose $(x, y) ∈ (P(A) \times P(B))$

By Cartesian definition $x ∈ P(A)$ and $y ∈ P(B)$. Then by power set definition $x ⊆ A$ and $y ⊆ B$. So, $(x, y) ⊆ A \times B$.

Therefore, $(x, y) ∈ P (A \times B)$.

Is this proof correct? If so, how can I improve my proof-writing? Any constructive-criticism will be welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the statement is in fact true.  For example, you have $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$ as an element on the LHS, but in general not on the RHS (in particular if $\emptyset$ is not an *element* of $A$ or $B$).

Comment: The statement would be true if by $(P(A) × P(B))$ you meant the set of all products $x × y$ with $x ∈ P(A)$ and $y ∈ P(B)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz that's a counterexample right? Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

This proof is not correct, nor is the result you're trying to prove even true.  The flaw is that $x\subseteq A$ and $y\subseteq B$ does not imply that $(x,y)\subseteq A\times B$.  It is true that if (and only if) $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ then $(x,y)\in A\times B$ (this is the definition of the set $A\times B$), but you can't replace $\in$ with $\subseteq$.

To show that $(x,y)\subseteq A\times B$, you have to prove that $(x,y)$ is a subset of $A\times B$.  But this doesn't even make sense to say: $(x,y)$ is an ordered pair, not a set.

(Well, in some contexts an ordered pair might be defined as a certain set.  But I don't know of any standard definition of it as a set such that it would be a subset of $A\times B$).

Comment: So you mean this statement as it is written is false? (P(A)×P(B)) is not the subset of P(A×B)? If so, what would be a counterexample for this statement?

Comment: And this would be true as: if(and only if) right? Thanks by the way.